# Как сделать, чтобы DatePicker открывался на определенной дате?

Tags: android, datepicker

```
private DatePicker mDatePicker = (DatePicker)v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_date_picker);
mDatePicker.init(calendar.YEAR, calendar.MONTH, calendar.DATE, null);
```

Открывается на дате выставленной в minDate в xml.

Comment: Покажите xml с DatePicker и как инициализируете `calendar`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_date_picker);
datePicker.updateDate(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

Comment: Пробовал так, результат тот же. (

Comment: @msp Все корректно

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d80f1a0ffda3cfc2a3955ea88588ba7a
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6762af4db0ec467993eab41c75856dae